# For loop gives only 1 as a result

Tags: pine-script

Can someone help me understand what’s wrong in this code? It basically gives me a output=1, which is not obviously correct.

```
a = ema(close,10)-ema(close,200)

var lowest = 0.00
if a<lowest
    lowest := a 

var highest = 0.00
if a>highest
    highest := a 

basis = max(-1*lowest,highest)
 
frequency(source,boundary) =>
    var r_count = 0.00
    var count = 0.00
    if source > boundary or source< -boundary
        count := count+1
    else 
        if source <boundary and source>-boundary
            r_count := r_count+1
    count/(count+r_count)
    

var output= 0.0
for i=0.00 to 1
    chosen= basis *i
    test=frequency(a,chosen)
    if test>=0.3 or test<=0.31
        break 
    output := i
```

I want that i go from 0.00, 0.01,..0.1,0.110.12,...0.99,1 and it have to stop when 0.30<test<0.31 and when that happen I want to know the value of i.

Thank's.

EDIT: Basically the code have to do this:

```
a = ema(close,10)-ema(close,200)

var lowest = 0.00
if a<lowest
    lowest := a 

var highest = 0.00
if a>highest
    highest := a 

basis = max(-1*lowest,highest)
 
frequency(source,percents) =>
    var r_count = 0.00
    var count = 0.00
    for i=0.00 to 1 by 0.01
        boundary= basis*i
        if source > boundary or source< -boundary
            count := count+1
        else 
            if source <boundary and source>-boundary
                r_count := r_count+1
        if (count/(count+r_count))>= percents and (count/(count+r_count))<= percents
            break
        i
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> I want that i go from 0.00, 0.01,..0.1,0.110.12,...0.99,1

By default, the step of the `for` loop is 1. `for i=0.00 to 1` has two steps: 0.00 and 1. If you want to change the step, you need to add `by 0.01` to the end of the loop.

> it have to stop when 0.30<test<0.31

Then your `if` condition is incorrect. The `if test>=0.3 or test<=0.31` line will be true if `test == 1` because `test>=0.3` would be true. As a result, your loop usually breaks on the first iteration. If you want to make sure test is between 0.3 and 0.31, you need to replace `or` with `and`.

Here's the part with both issues fixed:

```
var output= 0.0
for i=0.00 to 1 by 0.01
    chosen= basis *i
    test=frequency(a,chosen)
    if test>=0.3 and test<=0.31
        break 
    output := i

plot(output)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks's, but unfortunately I'm not getting the wright result. Ideally output=x and frequency(a,x) = 0.3 (or wathever value inserted in the for loop)

Comment: I've updated the main post, see it for a better explaination.